# Can I recover from association (joinTable) with reference to missing data

Tags: grails, many-to-many, join

I've read through a lot of posts and docs and must be missing something.

In my application (model below) I am having a data issue that seems to be out of my control where I have a categoryId in the join table JOBORDERCATEGORIES that has no corresponding row in the CATEGORY table. I am accessing the category data through getJobCategories() in the JobOrder. This is producing the following error when my Category table is missing a referenced row:

```
2012-03-07 08:02:10,223 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.SessionBinderJobListener  - Cannot flush Hibernate Sesssion, error will be ignored
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.matrixres.domain.Category#416191]
```

and my code is halting.

I have tried using ignoreNotFound but it is not helping me to get past the error above.

If I missed a post on the solution to this problem please link me to it otherwise thoughts are welcome on how to move forward. Perhaps there is a more direct route I will have to hammer in to achieve my goal of getting a good category list, but I am not familiar enough with the framework to know what is next. As a note, I cannot write to any of these tables.

thanks, rich

A simplified Version of my Model:

**Job Order Object:**

```
class JobOrder {
   def getJobCategories() {
        def cats = []
        try {
            def jocategories = this.categories
            if(!jocategories.isEmpty() && jocategories!=null){
                println "we got categories for ${this.id}"

                jocategories.each {  cat ->
                    if(cat?.parentCategoryID == 0){
                        if(cat.occupation != null){
                          cats <<  cat.occupation
                        } else {
                          cats <<  cat.name
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(e) {
            cats << "Other Area(s)"
        }
        cats
    }

  static mapping = {
    table 'dbo.JOBORDER'
    version false
    id generator: 'identity', column: 'JOBORDERID'

    /*
     * several other mapped columns deleted here
    */

    categories joinTable:[name:'jobOrderCategories', column: 'categoryId', key:'jobOrderID']
  }

  /*
    * several properties deleted here
    */
  static hasMany = [categories: Category] //several other hasMany associations exist

}
```

**Category Object:**

```
class Category {

    static mapping = {
        table 'CATEGORY'
        version false
        id generator: 'identity', column: 'categoryID'
        occupation column: 'OCCUPATION'
        name column: 'NAME'
        parentCategoryID column: 'PARENTCATEGORYID'       
        /*
         * several other mapped columns deleted here
         */

        jobOrders joinTable:[name:'jobOrderCategories', column: 'jobOrderID', key:'categoryId']
    }

    String name
    String occupation
    int parentCategoryID
    /*
     * several properties deleted here
     */

    static belongsTo = [JobOrder]
    static hasMany = [jobOrders:JobOrder]
}
```

**Join Table:**

```
class JobOrderCategories {
  static mapping = {
    table 'JOBORDERCATEGORIES'
    version false
    isDeleted column: 'ISDELETED'
    jobOrderID column: 'JOBORDERID'
    categoryId column: 'CATEGORYID'
  }

  Boolean isDeleted
  Integer jobOrderID
  Integer categoryId
}
```

Comment: You can't write to any of the tables as in you don't have direct DB write access? your App doesn't have DB write access? do you have update / delete access? Because truly, this is a data integrity problem and that is the solution. So if you must work around it, there most likely will be ugliness, and you may have to break down the ORM a bit to get to where you need to be (which I'm happy to help with if it's truly necessary, I've done that before, it's not the most fun thing ever though :/ )

Comment: The data I am accessing is read-only because it is synchronized from a vendor's (data owner's) off site system. It is for us to use internally as a local data store with no changes to their data. Changing the data breaks their one way synchronization and then we have to pay dollars to have them hard reset our store back to their external data. That's what I mean by I can't write to it. ;) I am now working on trying to make a job order handler that will allow us to recover from hibernate coughing up blood on this one. It really stinks to work with data that has no RI.

Comment: Yes, limited data access and third party integrations do kinda stink :) I wouldn't start trying to put a quarantine on hibernate just yet though. I'll write up a more formal answer, but basically the easy hack around this is to store the ids as ints rather than map them with GORM. Get back to you soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of situations aren't the most fun, but I have had to deal with this kind of Roll-Your-Own ORM problems before ;) Basically what you're going to want to do here is store the object properties not typed as Object references, but as ints, and while you'll lose some of the dynamic finder things GORM makes so nifty, you'll have a fairly straight-forward means of accessing the data that doesn't involve tangling yourself up with Hibernate's innards.

Basically, this will involve ditching your hasMany and belongsTo properties on JobOrder and Category. Instead, you'll want to do things like

```
def myJobOrder = JobOrder.get(yourId);
def myCategoryIds = JobOrderCategories.findAllByJobOrderID(myJobOrder.id)
def myCategories = Categories.withCriteria {
    in('id', myCategoryIds)
}
```

You can put variations of those traversals in helper methods on your classes, like for example, your getJobCategories method could become

```
class JobOrder {
//...
    def getJobCategories() {
        def myCategoryIds = JobOrderCategories.findAllByJobOrderID(this.id)
        def myCategories = Categories.withCriteria {
            in('id', myCategoryIds)
        }
    }
}
```

And so on. This is definitely not the prettiest thing in the world to deal with, and you lose your ability to traverse through things easily with GORM (ex a

```
jobOrder.withCriteria {
   categories {
     eq('name', blah)
   }
}
```

becomes a executeQuery type of situation.)
But overall, its not too bad to deal with :)
Hope that helps!

Comment: This actually is not horrible, I've had to do far worse in other language/framework environments. Let me wrap something around this and run some tests! Thanks.

Comment: Well I suppose perspective is very relative ;) I've started my career basically entirely in grails, and this makes things way less nice than normal. Compared to some of the hacks it would've taken in stock Java/Spring/Hibernate though, I fully believe it looks extremely clean by comparison ;) Let me know if things don't work out and you're in need of further inquiry!

Comment: Very good, using the concept above seems to be working fine. As a recap: 1) removed the belongsTo/hasMany relationships 2)added a composite key to the jobOrderCategory model 3) updated getJobCategories to retrieve a collection of jobOrderCategories with the findAllByJobOrderID 4) got a collection of categories withCriteria from the jobOrderCategoryCollection. Many Thanks!